# Determining if H is a subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would like to know if I have gone off track on this problem. Given

$$G = \langle \mathbb{R}^*, * \rangle$$ (set $\mathbb{R}$ excluding zero, and operation of multiplication), and

$$H = \{ 2^n3^m : m, n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

determine if H is a subgroup of G.

I know that, for H to be a subgroup, I must prove that

(i) for $$a, b \in H, ab \in H$$

(ii) for $$a \in H, a^{-1} \in H$$

For (i)

If I understand correctly, any ***a*** looks like $$a = 2^n3^n$$ So we could also say any ***b*** looks like $$b = 2^u3^v, u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$$ Then

$$ab = 2^n3^m2^u3^v$$
$$ab= 2^{n+u}3^{m+v}$$

and since $$ n + u, m + v \in \mathbb{Z}\ $$
The element ***ab*** must be in ***H***.

For (ii)

$$a^{-1} = (2^n3^m)^{-1}$$
$$a^{-1} = 2^{-n}3^{-m}$$

and since $$ -n, -m \in \mathbb{Z} \ \forall \ n, m \in \mathbb{Z} $$

There is an inverse for every element ***a***.

So (i) and (ii) are satisfied, and H is a subgroup of G.

Math is not a strong subject for me, so I am concerned I might be misunderstanding basic points of this proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct and everything is fine, as long as you show that $H$ is *non-empty* (because, groups are not empty: they always contain the identity).It is easy to show that $1 \in H$, for example.

The point is, both statements $i,ii$ above are statements that already assume that something is in $H$, and then want you to show that something else is in $H$. Ifthere was nothing in $H$ in the first place, then those statements would be vacuously true, although $H$ does not contain the identity. Therefore, as an extra condition, you should also check that $e \in H$, the identity.

---

Also, sometimes the  condition for being a subgroup is stated as :

i' : For every $a,b \in H$, we have $ab^{-1} \in H$. Note that this captures both i and ii in your question.

ii' : $e \in H$.

You can check that $H$ is a subgroup using just these conditions.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You are welcome!